# How insert very reference in doctrine

Tags: mysql, database, symfony, doctrine-orm, bigdata

I have 3 entities: `User`, `Page`, `Post`

In the `Post` entity:

```
class Post
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Page")
     */
    private $page;

    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection $subscribers Specify users that see this post.
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="wallPosts")
     */
    private $subscribers;
}
```

In the `Page` enity:

```
class Page
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User")
     */
    private $members;
}
```

When a post is published I want that all users that are ***members*** of `Page` are set as ***subsribers*** of `Post`

`$post->setSubscribers($post->getPage()->getMembers())`

**note**: `Page` can have several thousand users, what is best way that have best performance? Should I use a native query, database triggers or procedures?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in cycle. Subscribe 50 users per one iteration to new post. 
Do not forget to clean doctrine internal storage. The main idea is

```
$page = $post->getPage();
for ($i = 1;; ++$i) {
  $members = $page->getPagindatedMembers($i);
  if (empty($members)) {
     break;
  }
  foreach ($members as $member) {
     $post->addSubscriber($member);
  }
  $em->flush();
  $em->clear(Member::class);
}
```

Comment: thank you, but i think that it haven't a good performance for page that have about 50-100 thousands user

Comment: Sure,  but you can do it in async mode. Some AMQP implementation like RabbitMQ will help.

Comment: Anything that involves modifying 100K records will not be a good fit for a request/response php application regardless of how you implement it.  If you can do it with a database trigger then great.

Comment: I told about AMQP. Your controller pushes a message into broker and your worker should update related entities. If you try to update 100k rows in one query you can catch issues with their locking.